# Collision detection & animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, ios4

I am trying to get 'luke' to jump over an object to ensure that the game does not end, which he does but even if he avoids the object the game still ends, as if luke had not left his original location during the animation.

I used the UIView animateWithDuration in `-(void)touchesBegin` to try to achieve this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                 animations:^
 {
     luke.center = CGPointMake(luke.center.x +0, luke.center.y -60);
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed)
 {
     if (completed)
     {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                     animations:^     
          {
              luke.center = CGPointMake(luke.center.x +0, luke.center.y +60);
          }];
     }
```

I am also using `CGRectIntersectsRect` to tell me when the two objects collide

```
-(void)collision {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(luke.frame, smallboulder.frame)) {
    [self endgame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(luke.frame, largeboulder.frame)) {
    [self endgame];

}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(luke.frame, cactus.frame)) {
    [self endgame];
}
```

finally can i use an animation set up as a `NSArray` to show movement when jumping.

Many thanks

JP

Comment: Why are you using such an obsolete version of Xcode?

Comment: I am using a macbook4.1 and i cant upgrade beyond snow leopard. hence the obsolete version

Comment: Do you have a more modern PC? You can install Mavericks in a VM and work on that.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i did not think about VMs. Would any code i have put together in 3.2.6 need dramatic alterations in the latest version. I am trying to make my first app.

Comment: It is a pretty old version. There have been many changes that you'd want to incorporate. Also, if you want to upload to AppStore, you must use at least Xcode 5 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `UIView` animation methods to animate various properties, the animation is actually performed on something called the presentation layer. But when you use the view's `frame` accessor, it accesses the model layer (rather than the presentation layer), which holds the latest values (so it holds the designated frame after animation).

You should check for "luke"'s location using `luke.layer.presentationLayer.frame`.